# 10g ordering varchar columns when containing numbers in front

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, varchar2

I have an Oracle 10g DB and have a VARCHAR2 (2000 Character) column lets name it TEST which can contain numbers in front for example:

```
test
1test
3test
```

When I call "... order by TEST asc" or simply "... order by TEST"

I get the results ordered like

```
test
1test
3test
```

But I would like to get the results ordered like this:

```
1test
3test
test
```

So the numbered inserts first, is there a method to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is your [NLS_SORT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams130.htm) set to? (`select sys_context('USERENV', 'NLS_SORT') from dual`). If it is `BINARY` then the sort order is based on the numeric value of each character, so it's dependant on the database character set. If it's something else then you might want to override it.

You can change the sort order at database or session level by modifying that parameter, but you can also change it for a single query:

```
order by nlssort(test,'NLS_SORT=BINARY')
```

Depending on your character set you might need to experiment with different values instead of `BINARY`. You can get a list of all the valid values with `select value from v$nls_valid_values where parameter = 'SORT'`. But note the potential performance impacted mentioned in the NLS_SORT documentation.

The `nlssort()` function is documented [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions099.htm).

Comment: your suggestion works ... I tried with `order by nlssort(test,'NLS_SORT=BINARY')` tnx very much for the hint

Answer (score 4):

You could replace the previous answers substr test with a regexp

```
order by case when regexp_instr(test,'[0-9]+') = 1 then 
   to_number(regexp_substr(test,'[0-9]+')) 
else 
   null 
end nulls last, test
```

It should be something like that - you can tweak the regexp according to what you want.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
order by case when substr(test,1,1) between '0' and '9' then 1 else 2 end,
         test
```

Comment: I suppose there could be more digits, though... Sorting those would be tricky.

Comment: also you could probably get rid off the `substr`, a simple `test between '0' and '9'` should have the same effect.

Comment: jap it could be inserts like 

`
123-345aaaa
23kkkr45
aaaaakkk
`

and so on

Comment: @simonC: for these cases, you might need to normalize how you store the data (break it in two columns). Do you have a lot of data?

Comment: actualy I can't brake in two columns because i store there file names that the user is uploading...and it could be anythig, it could be starting also with the $ character...if there is no simple way to sort this in db I will try to sort it in code...anyway I would asume that if a string has a number as first character would be put in front of some other string starting with a alhabetic chatacter

Answer (score 0):

Using substr is working fine.If we want numbers in ascending order and character in descending order.what is the workaround.